Per-Item inter rater reliability with multiple values and raters
I am trying to find the best statistical calculation to measure the agreement between 72 different raters on one item. My goal is to convey in a statistic how spread the raters are on their rating and whether there is a sort of consensus/agreement.
Data: I have 72 responses to a 5 question survey using numerical values (Likert Scale 1-6).
Ex:



Rater
Question 1
Question 2




1
5
4


2
1
2


3
3
2



I would like to calculate their agreement per item (as each survey question is a completely separate question which doesn't seem to match the same idea as if you were rating different restaurants - correct me if I am wrong). Other IRR calculations do not seem to work great on one item and require multiple items for chance.
I thought I should maybe focus more on the variance but am not sure. I would appreciate recommendations and any Python implementations/libraries.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
